# Setting height field in Create TIN" tool in ArcMap when using it in model?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, 3d-analyst, tin

When using the tool on its own, you can pick the height field manually. I want this choice to be an option in a model, however I cannot add any parameter for the options in the box. Is this somehow possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The 'Height Field' can't be a standalone option, since it is always related to each of the input feature classes. But you can se the 'Input feature class' as parameter of the model, the Height Field option will be visible:

Set Input Feature Class as parameter:

[image]

The this is what you get when running the model:

[image]

Comment: This works when I do the following: rightclick on tool --> make variable -> from parameter -> input feature class. It does not work when I use some output (from a clip for example) and connect it as input feature class OR insert a feature class variable and connect it as input feature class.

Comment: @MapEngine - No, indeed. The data type of this parameter is `value table`, not `feature class`. You'd probably better use python to do this.

Comment: I guess I'll have to, there's no value table variable, nor did other variables I tried work. Thanks for the help!